# Material Design md-menu madness

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using Angularjs with Angular Material and I have an `<md-menu>` that's opened when an `<md-button>` is clicked. I render the menu with an ng-repeat that looks like this:

```
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in orderItem.searchItems">
                <md-button ng-click="orderItem.searchMenuHit($event, '{{item.field}}')">
                    {{item.caption}}
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
```

If I right click on a menu item and inspect it with the debugger, it shows ng-click as orderItem.searchMenuHit($event,'STK_NUM') which is what I expect.

As shown in the image below:
[image]

When orderItem.searchMenuHit gets called it receives '{{item.field}}' as the value of its second parameter.

I'm not sure why this is, or how to address it. Obviously when the menu it actually rendered the item is rendered with the correct ng-click code, however; it seems when an item is clicked, the item is somehow re-rendered and the angular expression, even thought it's valid, is not evaluated.

Comment: you have the parameter in quotes, so it is sending a string literal to the function. take the quotes off and it should be fine

Comment: No, I already tried that and then there are no quotes around the value and it's interpreted as a variable. It's quite normal to include an Angular expression within quotes if that's the desired output.

Comment: Ah, i figured based on the question that you wanted that to be sent as a variable. What is the desired result then?

Comment: The original question states the desired result. "If I right click on a menu item and inspect it with the debugger, it shows ng-click as orderItem.searchMenuHit($event,'STK_NUM') which is what I expect."

Comment: Try it  like this : `ng-click="orderItem.searchMenuHit($event, item.field)"`

Comment: `When orderItem.searchMenuHit gets called it receives '{{item.field}}' as the value of its second parameter.` Can you clarify what you mean by the value of its second parameter?

Comment: The 2nd parameter of the searchMenuHit function literally ends up with a value for {{item.field}}.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if I'm doing something silly that made this more difficult than it should be or not, but for whatever reason, I could not get item.field to be properly passed as a parameter to my controller. I ended up passing the entire item object and that works fine.

My entire `<md-menu>` snippet now looks like this:

```
<md-menu>
        <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
            <i class="material-icons md-dark">search</i>
        </md-button>
        <md-menu-content>
            <md-menu-item ng-repeat="item in orderItem.searchItems">
                <!--<md-button ng-click={{orderItem.getShortCutItem(item)}}>-->
                <md-button ng-click="orderItem.searchMenuHit(item)">
                    {{item.caption}}
                </md-button>
            </md-menu-item>
        </md-menu-content>
    </md-menu>
```